# Dynamics Navision 2017 - Insert Sales Order using Web Services

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, soap, navision, dynamics-nav

We have Navision Dynamics 2017 which has Sales Orders exposed as a SOAP web service. Technically, I am supposed to be able to create sales orders via this web service.

We also have another system built in C# .NET that has staff sales orders that need to go into Navision. This ordering system has all the information like customer, item, quantity, price etc to be able to create a valid order in Navision.

Can someone tell me how I can call the service and create a sales header and Line from the staff sales orders system into Navision..

Preferably a walk through tutorial would be ideal. I've searched and can't seem to find one that I can follow

Answer (score 0):

The classic 'goto' for NAV services was always the following blog post, albeit it's an example for PHP.  Take into account changes are required in NAV to be able to interact with the service (Hint: Activate NTLM):

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php/

There is now an updated version by the same autor, complementing the original post:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2016/11/06/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php-take-2/

Example for C#:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-web-reference/

Example for completing a Sales Order:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2009/11/17/extending-page-web-services-and-creating-a-sales-order-again/

Answer (score 0):

I googled it for you. Is for Nav 2013, but it is all the same in 2017.

https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/ishwarsblogspot/archive/2016/09/26/register-and-consume-codeunit-as-a-web-service-in-nav-2013-r2

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the rest API that I developed with .NET Core 5, I created 2 pages (one for sales header and one for sales lines) and one code-unit for invoking calculate discount action on NAV.

```
[Route("order")]
[HttpPost]
private async Task<dynamic> createOrder(orderDTO request)
    {
        var systemService = this.OrderServiceProvider.GetProxy();
        List<OrderServiceReference.Sales_Quote_Line> lineList = new List<OrderServiceReference.Sales_Quote_Line>();
        foreach (OrderLine orderLine in request.Sales_Quote_Line)
        {
            Sales_Quote_Line line = new Sales_Quote_Line()
            {
                Type = OrderServiceReference.Type.Item,
                TypeSpecified = true,
                No = orderLine.No,
                Quantity = orderLine.Quantity,
                QuantitySpecified = true
            };
            lineList.Add(line);
        }
        var task = await systemService.CreateAsync(new OrderServiceReference.Create()
        {
            Dis_SQ = new Dis_SQ()
            {
                Salesperson_Code = request.Salesperson_Code,
                Sell_to_Customer_No = request.Sell_to_Customer_No,
                Order_Date = new DateTime(),
                SalesLines = lineList.ToArray()
            }
        });
        var salesQuotes = task.Dis_SQ;
        // var systemService2 = new DiscountServiceReference.Dis_Discount_Cal_PortClient();
        var calculateSystemWebService = this.CalculateDiscountServiceProvider.GetProxy();
        await calculateSystemWebService.CalcOffersSHAsync(new CalcOffersSH()
        {
            Body = new CalcOffersSHBody()
            {
                pDocNo = salesQuotes.No,
                pDocType = 0
            }
        });
        // get sales lines
        var systemService1 = this.OrderLinesServiceProvider.GetProxy();
        var task1 = await systemService1.ReadMultipleAsync(new SalesOrderServiceReference.ReadMultiple()
        {
            filter = new HHT_SO_Filter[]
            {
                new HHT_SO_Filter()
                {
                    Criteria = salesQuotes.No,
                    Field = HHT_SO_Fields.Document_No
                }
            },
            bookmarkKey = "",
            setSize = 200
        });
        return new
        {
            sales_header = task.Dis_SQ,
            sales_line = task1.ReadMultiple_Result1
        };
 }
```

If you need any more help comment below.